# How do I calculate the size of a sphere of evenly spaced points if the distance of those points is known

Tags: geometry

I have X number of points evenly spaced and each is no closer to each other or the container wall than a distance Y, and for each point either the nearest point is at distance Y or the container wall is at distance Y. If this container is a sphere, how large will the sphere be in terms of X and Y?

Answer (score 1):

A good approximation can be found by considering each point to be in the centre of a cube of side $Y$. These cubes cannot intersect and all are within a sphere of radius $R-\frac{Y}{2}.$

So, when $Y$ is small compared to $R$ we can consider $$\frac{4}{3}\pi (R-\frac{Y}{2})^3\approx XY^3.$$

$$R\approx Y\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt[3]\frac{3X}{4\pi}\right)$$